# Cant Compile c++ library with static library

Tags: c++, c, linux, static-libraries

I downloaded a C++ library that I want to use for some simulation.

It includes:
1- source file "main.cpp"
2- header files in "Include" folder
3- static precompiled library "libhj.a"
4- Cmakelist.txt

In their manual they are suggesting to use GNU & Cmake to compile and produce the executable file.

I tried several solution with out hope!
1- I downloaded MinGW and Cmake on my Windows 7 and tried to use them to first produce the Makefile, then use "make" command to produce the exe file, but didn't work properly.
2- So I switched to linux "Ubuntu" and this is what I get:

```
`enter code here`CMakeFiles/exe.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2d1): undefined reference to `HJB_SL::HJB_SL(mrp, cp, cp, pp, gp, ppp, slp)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2d9): undefined reference to `HJB::initFiles() const'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ea): undefined reference to `HJB::postprocess()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x49c): undefined reference to `HJB_FD::HJB_FD(mrp, cp, cp, pp, gp, ppp, fdp)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`
```

Could any body guide me to what to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Would help to know what library.

Comment: for sure, it won't work in way/shape/form under windows, unless you're cross compiling (by the maturity of your question, I'm guessing this is foreign to you).  A library of type (.a) is some variety of *nix, do you know which one?  do a `file libhj.a` and post the results here as well as the source of your makefile (that will provide us a start.....)

Comment: Note that you shouldn't have a file named main.cpp and a result file named main.cpp.o - I think you're in trouble here.....  You need to do quite a bit more study on how to compile and link/ld programs on your current OS

Comment: @KevinDTimm - source.cpp.o is the convention that CMake uses for naming object files.

Comment: Please paste your command line for linking.

Comment: I suggest you post your CMakeLists.txt. Since it will create the linker instructions.